# Convert Redeemer, Datum or Script Parameter to JSON

Tags: plutus, transaction

By following the alonzo-testnet exercises, I'm right now having to build a transaction with `cardano-cli`. One of the arguments necessary to consume a script is the datum, another is the redeemer, both of which should be in a JSON file (or value).

Is there any reference of how `Data` should be expressed in JSON? Because I tried converting it with Data.Aeson in Haskell, but received the following error

```
JSON object does not match the schema.
Expected a single field named "int", "bytes", "string", "list" or "map".
Unexpected object field(s): {"contents":{"getPubKeyHash":"3e7181860513a17dfa44d69232429e5c328e79c748d4a176950c42b6"},"tag":"Collect"}
```

Also, is there any library to make my life easier, so I can be able to easily convert my redeemers into JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Reading some old messages in discord, someone mentioned that I could use `encode (scriptDataToJson ScriptDataJsonDetailedSchema $ fromPlutusData data)`, taken from [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/main/resources/plutus-sources/plutus-helloworld/app/plutus-helloworld-bytestring.hs#L43), so I made a `redeemerJSON` function defined as follows:

```
redeemerJSON :: DistributionRedeemer -> ByteString
redeemerJSON dr =
  encode (scriptDataToJson ScriptDataJsonDetailedSchema $ fromPlutusData (PlutusTx.toData dr))
```

Of course some imports are necessary, but I believe you can use this same approach for the datum and other script parameters too.

Comment: I would make it even more general to: 

```haskell
plutusDataToJSON :: PlutusTx.ToData a => a ->  Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
plutusDataToJSON = encode . (scriptDataToJson ScriptDataJsonDetailedSchema) . fromPlutusData . Plutus.toData```

Answer (score 0):

The Cardano-node github is the best resource that I have found

### JSON conversion

> Script data is similar to JSON but not exactly the same. It has some
> deliberate limitations such as no support for floating point numbers
> or special forms for null or boolean values. It also has limitations
> on the length of strings.
>
> On the other hand, unlike JSON, it
> distinguishes between byte strings and text strings. It also supports
> any value as map keys rather than just string. It also supports
> alternatives / tagged unions, used for  representing constructors for
> Plutus data values.
>
> continues ....

Further extensive details in Cardano-node github file [ScriptData.hs](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/c1efb2f97134c0607c982246a36e3da7266ac194/cardano-api/src/Cardano/Api/ScriptData.hs#L254)